# How can I use the mPDF with yii?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, mpdf

I am using yii framework to genereate pdf reports. using yiireport extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiireport I was able to generate the report. There are three options for generating the pdf, that is using TcPDF, DomPDF or mPDF library. Both TcPDF, DomPDF is working but mPDF is not working. How can I use the mPDF with yii. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

mPDF isn't supplied with yiireport by default. Yiireport installation steps say:

```
3) Download a PDF library, like mPDF and copy to protected/vendors directory
```

Then you should configure it in yiireport.php:

```
return array(
    'pdfRenderer' => 'mpdf',
     // You should extract mpdf.zip contents, which you got from
     // http://www.mpdf1.com
     // and point 'pdfRenderedPath' to it
    'pdfRendererPath' => 'application.vendors.mpdf', 
    'templatePath' => 'application.views.reports'
);
```

Comment: I have followed those steps for installation. And not only mPDF but TcPDF, DomPDF are also not supplied with yii. The installation of those two were successful. Problem is with mPDF installation.

Comment: you have showed us neither error/exception, nor your config file.

Comment: There is no php error or exception, it only shows 404 page not found.